# gnupg: How to exchange keys with key server

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

How do you exchange keys with via key server?

Worked example would be great with send and find+retrieve.

I know `gpg --send-keys` is the command but how do you find the keyid (tried all output from -`--list-keys`). `--keyserver keys.gpugp.net` works with `--send-keys` but not with `--search-keys` (says bad uri). Which keys should I publish? What key server to publish to. Despite being a pretty simple program, the gnugp docs are terrible (broken links, missing info).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### What Went Wrong

You're dealing with two problems:

1. `gpg --search-keys` searches keyservers, not locally. Use `gpg --list-keys` instead.
2. GnuPGs keyserver domain is `keys.gnupg.net`, not `keys.gpugp.net` (typo). Additionally, you have to prefix a protocol, `hkp://` is supported by most keyservers.

### Relevant Commands for Exchanging Keys

- `gpg --send-keys [keyid]`: Send key id to a keyserver
- `gpg --recv-keys [keyid]`: Fetch key id from a keyserver
- `gpg --search-keys [needle]`: Search for keys on a keyserver that contain "needle", eg. in a UID
- `gpg --list-keys [needle]`: List all local keys that contain "needle", eg. in a UID

To select another keyserver than the default one configured, use `--keyserver [URI]`. Make sure to use a complete and valid URI like `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`, or `hkp://keys.gnupg.net` (which actually refers to the SKS keyserver pool ourdays).

Comment: Should I publish my pub, sub or both keys?

Comment: Publish all public keys. You want to use your subkeys for "daily work", so they need to be published. Signatures are bound to the primary key, so for validating that one is necessary, too. But you do not have to care about all that, GnuPG does for you, just use `gpg --send-keys [primary]` and it will also upload your (public) subkeys.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion: it doesn't matter which key server you use. They do synchronise their keys.

I use pool.sks-keyservers.net which is a virtual load balancing key server.